What are the best Webcam features for recording whiteboard videos in high quality
I stand in front of a whiteboard or a smartboard and teach online. Want to record my mathematics and science lecture videos (1-1.5 hours each) for YouTube but in the best quality. Many cameras provide 1080 at 60fps but their video quality output when seen by students appears different.
End result should be like this example 


Was thinking of Logitech Brio 4K Ultra HD or Obsbot Tiny 2 or Insta Link 360 type of 4K PTZ camera because I work alone, but I am not sure. Am a math genius but zero at Web Cameras :(
Budget is not a problem. Suggestions for features to look in those Webcams are welcome.
Thanks for your advice in advance

This is not an answer, but a long comment.
That is a really bad-quality video. The images on the back look good because he is probably superimposing them. But the video shoot itself looks very bad. The camera has a very small dynamic range.
An additional problem, probably the main one is bad light. He is probably using low-quality fluorescent light and he is not white-balancing the result. And the position is not good either, It just happens to be on the ceiling...
But it makes no sense to keep talking about an example of a random video on the internet. It would be better to improve YOUR setting, so post an example of what you have to see what can be improved.

Video quality output when seen by students appears different

That is a problem on the student's side. Probably they have low bandwidth, or a small screen, or a broken screen. You can not measure that.

Was thinking of an X 4K camera.

Having a 4k or 8k camera will not do anything with bad light, and if the students still are using the same screen.
Besides taking a look at how your setup looks, there is something really simple you can and should do.
Do not shoot at 60FPS.
If your students have low bandwidth, don't send them unnecessary high framerate for a professor talking. If you use 30FPS you are sending half the information, so you can actually double the quality of the compression!
If your camera shoots at 24FPS even better!
But, again, post some screenshots of your setup.

In order to decide on a new camera, you should pay attention to the lens: the focal length, and this depends on the space you have and the distances between you and your board.

Well, that sample video looks great on my 6ft OLED TV :) Trust me, the students mostly have very good Internet speed and the right viewing screens. My post is about Webcam features for video recording.
What I am actually asking is with which cam can I shoot similar quality videos at 1080 60fps?
Which of those allows locking the focus on the whiteboard so that the text does not become blurry when the teacher moves and the camera auto focuses?
My other

Distance between the camera and board is around 1 to 1.5 m

Now, you are asking another question about autofocus, or manual/fixed focus. Then simply look for that spec in the features of the cameras, or look for a small aperture like f/8.
